# wifi is not working in my ASUS laptop on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet, asus

I have installed ubuntu 12.04 with windows 7 on my ASUS laptop, the wireless connection is working in windows but not in ubuntu, only wired connection is working in ubuntu. I have tried so many solutions but it is still not working. I am new in ubuntu. Thanks in advance.

Here is the output of **lspci | grep 'Network'** command.

```
asus@asus-X550CA:~$ lspci | grep 'Network'
02:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7630
```

Comment: Could we get the output of `lspci | grep 'Network'` so that we can see what wireless card you have in your laptop?